# How to get my windows conda to recognize my ANTs installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, path, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My conda environment that runs python code is on my Windows 10.

I installed ANTs successfully in my Ubuntu- Windows subsystem for Linux.

How do I get my Windows to recognize this now? How do I export the WSL path to my Windows path variable?

This is my WSL Ubuntu in my Windows 10 system, with Ants and N4BiasFieldCorrection
[image]

This is my conda environment in Windows 10 unable to find the installed ANTs
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you are asking at the moment. Ubuntu is installed as a separate sub-system in Windows and applications installed in that subsystem are not accessible in Windows. This might change soon but I don't think it's possible right now.

Comment: Oh, that's bad. Since the ANTs help said hey window users, go ahead and install WSL, I thought there was some way to make it work. Dammit.

Comment: Post a link to what you are referring to as the ANTS help and I’ll take a look.

Comment: "From here, it should be possible to obtain the ANTs source code and compile as one would on Linux or Mac OS." So I thought my windows conda would do this fine after I got all the steps right.

Comment: That means that you can get and compile the source in true Linux subsystem but past that I have no clue how the project works. I’ll find you on chat.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have to create the conda environment in your WSL, then you can work with it from Windows using Visual Studio Code with [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) extension.